# Python program stops running after user input in IDLE

Tags: python, shell, python-idle, raw-input

I'm currently in problem set 0 for course 6.00 on MIT OpenCourseware. I know it's a simple problem, and I think I've figured out a couple different approaches, and even plugged in other people's answers to check but every time that I run them in IDLE after the first raw_input prompt it stops running the code. It's like it gets to that point, I put in my answer, press return, and it does...nothing. I'm using version 2.7.10 by the way.

My computer isn't indenting either, and just taking me to the next form so forgive the disarray in this code.

```
dob = raw_input("What is your date of birth?")

lastName = raw_input("What is your last name?")

print (dob + ' ' + lastName)
```

It will get to asking me "What is your date of birth?", I put in my date of birth, and then it stops running. I'm pretty sure it's less of a problem with the code but just my own user error in using the shell. Please help me!

Comment: Did you try putting a simple `raw_input()` at the end of your program?

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall python?

Comment: In what way are you running this in IDLE? Are you saving it as a .py file using a separate text editor and doing "open..." in IDLE and then selecting "Run -> Run Module"? Or are you copying all the text to the clipboard and pasting the entire thing into the shell window and hitting enter? Or something else?

Comment: My [chatroom associate](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/26309786#26309786) informs me that pasting multiple statements all at once into IDLE is not advised: "you can only do one statement per line in IDLE". So, if that's what you're doing, don't do that.

Comment: Running that code from an IDLE editor works fine, so you must be doing something else.  Kevin is correct about pasting only one statement.